# verify function SAS to sql

Tags: sql, pyspark, sas

I have a verify function in SAS in a select query as below. May I know how to convert that in SQL to use in pyspark.

select substr(upercase(strip(emp)),verify(strip(emp),"0")) as id from Emp_table.

Answer (score 0):

`VERIFY(target-expression, search–expression)`

The VERIFY function returns the position of the first character in target-expression that is not present in search-expression. If there are no characters in target-expression that are unique from those in search-expression, VERIFY returns a 0.

Your search-expression is a single character `0` so the processing that is occurring is selecting the `emp` value without its leading zeroes.

Looks like you want to `ltrim` with expression `trim(LEADING '0' ...`